# Vnc4server not working on non-root user

Tags: dconf

I am trying to start vncserver on non-root user but it fails. It works on root. Here is log file: http://pasteonline.org/izrfwejDG/

I tried to fix it by adding this line to user-dirs.dirs file but it didn't help:
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$uid"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run it as non-root because it requires root privileges. The log files say `Permission denied` which mean the program does noto have permission to create directories unless they are root